# Where is the facebook page feed subscription field in webhooks ( Facebook graph API)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Few months ago I created a facebook app where I added "feed" subscription field in Webhooks section. See the screenshot of the previous app.

[image]

Today I created a new facebook app where I can't find the "feed" subscription field in Webhooks section. Where has it gone? Facebook removed it or something else? See the new app's screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe all the other entries are currently on lockdown due to this

https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/

I think you see "messages" because you've configured the messaging product, otherwise chances are that you wouldn't even see the 'Page' topic in the topics list.

Comment: Do you believe this will unlock in future?

Comment: Il looks like they are trying to tighten up privacy by limiting events while they figure out how to make those api work. I think they'll come back, but under another form and with a whole new sets of reviews.